# Optimize WP custom SQL query with multiple postmeta rows

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm working on a custom plugin to add a inventory management feature to my current WooCommerce store, and I'm on the edge of performance with the query I came up to in order to merge data from my custom table and the postmeta table.

The following SQL query does the job and gets me all desired data from the DB, but is highly slow and to my opinion not optimized at all, working in 0.1s for only 122 products in the test environment.

```
SELECT 
 i.ID AS item_id, 
 i.product_type AS item_product_type,
 i.product_id AS item_product_id, 
 i.serial_number AS item_serial_number, 
 i.entry_type AS item_entry, 
 i.state AS item_state, 
 i.status AS item_status, 
 i.location AS item_location, 
 i.position AS item_position, 
 i.purchase_cost AS item_purchase_cost, 
 i.overhead_cost AS item_overhead_cost, 
 i.retail_price AS item_retail_price, 
 i.private AS item_private,
 pm_sku.meta_value AS item_sku,
 pm_designation.meta_value AS item_designation,
 pm_cat.meta_value AS item_category,
 pm_reference.meta_value AS item_reference
FROM wprc_inventory_items as i
LEFT JOIN wprc_postmeta AS pm_sku ON pm_sku.post_id = i.product_id AND pm_sku.meta_key = '_sku'
LEFT JOIN wprc_postmeta AS pm_designation ON pm_designation.post_id = i.product_id AND pm_designation.meta_key = 'spare_designation'
LEFT JOIN wprc_postmeta AS pm_brand ON pm_brand.post_id = i.product_id AND pm_brand.meta_key = 'spare_brand'
LEFT JOIN wprc_postmeta AS pm_cat ON pm_cat.post_id = i.product_id AND pm_cat.meta_key = 'spare_category'
LEFT JOIN wprc_postmeta AS pm_reference ON pm_reference.post_id = i.product_id AND pm_reference.meta_key = 'spare_reference';
```

How can I manage to get the same output data with an optimized query ?

**EDIT : New query**

I managed to work the following query (with less data accessed and returned), working fine form phpMyAdmin (results given in approx 0.02s for 122 rows. However, Query Monitor plugin throws a Slow Query notice ... How will that work on the Production site, with more than 5k entries ?

```
SELECT 
        i.ID AS item_id, 
        i.serial_number AS item_serial_number, 
        i.state AS item_state, 
        i.status AS item_status, 
        max(case when pm.meta_key = '_sku' then pm.meta_value end) item_sku,
        max(case when pm.meta_key = 'spare_designation' then pm.meta_value end) item_designation,
        max(case when pm.meta_key = 'spare_brand' then pm.meta_value end) item_brand,
        max(case when pm.meta_key = 'spare_category' then pm.meta_value end) item_category,
        max(case when pm.meta_key = 'spare_reference' then pm.meta_value end) item_reference
        
     FROM wprc_inventory_items as i
     LEFT JOIN wprc_postmeta AS pm ON (pm.post_id = i.product_id AND pm.meta_key IN ('_sku', 'spare_designation', 'spare_brand', 'spare_category', 'spare_reference'))
     WHERE i.product_type = 'spare'
     GROUP BY i.ID
```

Comment: This is a notorious  WordPress performance problem, due to imperfect database indexing. Try this plugin to get better performance.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Comment: I went on with the mentioned plugin and all seems fine, went back to an acceptable time. Thanks